# How to display success message correctly and delete it when the page is refreshed

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to display a success message when a form is submitted. I did that by

```
<?php
    if(isset($email)){  
        echo "<p class='alert alert-successful'>Thank you, we will be in touch soon</p>";
    }
?>
```

But this way, the message stays on the page even when the page is refreshed.
How do I display a success message that gets deleted after a refresh?

I am only just learning WordPress and php, I am probably doing this all wrong. I don't want to use a plugin because I am only collecting an email (and sending the info to admin email), and using a plugin seemed like an overkill.

Comment: Assuming you are looking in the admin, start with Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You’re looking for Flash Messages. Flash Messages are messages stored in session and deleted right after they are retrieved. You can find some implementation on github: https://github.com/plasticbrain/PhpFlashMessages

```
<?php 

// Start a Session
// Read about managing session with WordPress

// Instantiate the class
$fm = new \Plasticbrain\FlashMessages\FlashMessages();

// Process form e.g. send an email and add success message
$msg->success('Thank you for sending message!');

// Display message
if( $fm->hasMessages('success') ) {

    /**
     * This line will display success message and also remove it
     * from session. After refresh $fm->hasMessages('success')
     * will return false
     */ 
    $fm->display('success'); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. Part of my problem is that I don't know what exactly I am looking for, so this is a great help.